# Data table with pagination, getting row data by pressing a button in the specified row, is only working in first page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, button, datatable, row

I have a Data table with n row and 5 visible columns, one of this columns as a drop down button which leads to 2 buttons one to download and other to resubmit file. I'm using pagination and the problem is that this buttons only work in the first page, the other pages when i click any of those buttons, they don't even run the code. Could you guys help me solving these??

Here is my Data table code:

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
        table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,                
            columns: [
                { visible: false },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { type: "date" },
                {
                    "render": function () {
                        return '<span class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Actions</button><div class="dropdown-menu"><input type="button" name="DownloadFile" class="dropdown-item" value="Download"><input type="button" name="ResubmitFile" class="dropdown-item" href="" value="Resubmit"></div></span>'
                    }
                }
            ],
            order: [[4, "desc"]]
        });

        $("input[name='DownloadFile']").on("click", function (el) {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");                                            
            window.open("/DataManagement/DownloadFile/" + id);             
        });

        $("input[name='ResubmitFile']").on("click", function (el) {
            var uploadId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
            var req = $.get("/DataManagement/ResubmitFileToProject", { UploadId: uploadId });
            req.done(function (res) {                                     
                TreatSubmissionResult(null, null, res);
            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is, on document ready (once you've loaded the page), those events are bound to the elements existing in the DOM. The DOM does not have the buttons on the 2nd, 3rd, ... and n pages yet because those elements are only created when you're navigating to their specific page.

What you want to do is, bind the event to a parent element using `.on()`.

Use the script below, I attached the event to the datatable stored on `var table` then added the target element as parameter;

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
        table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,                
            columns: [
                { visible: false },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { type: "date" },
                {
                    "render": function () {
                        return '<span class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Actions</button><div class="dropdown-menu"><input type="button" name="DownloadFile" class="dropdown-item" value="Download"><input type="button" name="ResubmitFile" class="dropdown-item" href="" value="Resubmit"></div></span>'
                    }
                }
            ],
            order: [[4, "desc"]]
        });

        $("#dataTable").on("click", "input[name='DownloadFile']", function (el) {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");                                            
            window.open("/DataManagement/DownloadFile/" + id);             
        });

        $("#dataTable").on("click", "input[name='ResubmitFile']", function (el) {
            var uploadId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
            var req = $.get("/DataManagement/ResubmitFileToProject", { UploadId: uploadId });
            req.done(function (res) {                                     
                TreatSubmissionResult(null, null, res);
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: - Before all, thank you Jerdine for your answer i really wasn't aware of  the relation between the document ready and the DOM, though it makes totally sense  now that you explained it!
- About the code it ins't working using $(table), i tried it and even the first page buttons weren't working. I just change it to $('#dataTable')  and it works fine, maybe because table var is pointing to the data table configurations instead of the table itself!?

Comment: thanks for the notice, I corrected the answer. Good luck with the project!